# Limit a text file to 100MB

Tags: logs, cron

I have several log files on my server that I would like to limit to 100MB large.  I'm considering creating a cron job that will run once a month and remove the oldest characters (closest to the top) from each log file, making each 100 megs or less in size. How can I do this?

Comment: this is situation when you should consider to use logrotate

Comment: Your cron approach would make the file _over_, not _under_ 100 megs large.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46549/logrotate-not-truncating-open-file/46571#46571

Answer (score 3):

> I am considering creating a cron job that will run once a month and remove the oldest characters (closest to the top) from each log file, making each 100 megs of less in size.

There are some problems that can arise with this methodology, so make sure first that the logging process is okay and continues to log when you edit a file this way.  If it holds the file handle open, it's probably a bad idea.

The normal way to manage logs is with `logrotate`, but note there are potential problems with that too -- some applications will react poorly to having their log files swapped.  The system logger actually falls into this category, and must be signalled post rotation to reopen the new log.

A similar option that avoids interrupting the process, if it can log to standard output or standard error, is to use [pipelog](http://www.cognitivedissonance.ca/cogware/pipelog/).  Pipelog acts as an intermediary to the process and the log file so that you can signal it to rotate or delete the log without interrupting or disturbing anything:

```
> someprocess | pipelog someprocess.logfile &
[pipelog 5334] Using 'someprocess.logfile' as a log file.
```

You can then rotate the log by sending pipelog SIGUSR1: `kill -s USR1 5334`, or delete it and start a new one with SIGUSR2.

Comment: You can use `postrotate` in your configuration file to restart your program (system logger or whatever) to avoid the "problems" you talk about.

Comment: @YoMismo Yes, that's why I said "must be signalled post rotation".  I didn't get further into the use of logrotate here because there are already copious explanations of that online.

Answer (score 2):

Use `logrotate`, it rotates your logs AND compress them for you if you want. Most probably it will already be running on your system, so create a file in /etc/logrotate.d to tell logrotate how to treat your logs. Check the man file for specs...

Answer (score -1):

`man split` will help you. Especially the `-b` flag.